# How to hide/show cmd window?

Tags: c, windows

I created a Win32 Console application, and hide the cmd window. So if my application is running, it can be seen only by the running processes. If there is a way, i want to modify my applicaition in the following way: 
If i define a parameter it should show the cmd window, but if i don't use this parameter then it should running without showing the cmd window.

I have disabled showing the cmd window the following way:

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS" )

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
 ...
 ...
 ...
}
```

Has anyone an idea how to do this?

kampi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lpCmdLine parameter to WinMain gives you access to the command-line for the program.  You can simply read its value and then take the appropriate action based on its value.

EDIT: The actual mechanics of displaying a console in Windows are a bit tricky.  You have to create the console, then redirect the standard output streams to write to it.  There's a great discussion of this [here](http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm) that does a great job detailing how this works and what code you need to get the job done.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Ok, i read the value, but how do i enable/show the window? Could you please help me a little?

Comment: @Kampi- Apologies; I thought you were getting tripped up by the command-line reading, not the console.  I've edited my answer with more detail on how to do this.  I hope it's useful!

Answer (score 0):

Since you said in the comment in the other answer, that you can well manage the command line parameter part, here's the other part that might help you. I hope you need to hide the console window, right?

Anyway, try the following (Untested):

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindowHandle(),SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: The function is GetConsoleWindow(), which returns a handle.